# Django: How to dynamically set view cache timeout value?

Tags: django

Within the view itself, I want to be able to set the cache timeout value upon returning a result. The reason for this is if the view returned an error, I want the timeout to be shorter.

Right now, I have the timeout set as static:

```
url(r'^view/(.+)/', cache_page(24 * 60 * 60)(MyView.as_view()), name='view')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually in your view class. Something like:

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response_data = cache.get('some_key')
        if response_data is None:
            response = super(MyView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
            cache.set('some_key', response.content, 300)
        else:
            response = HttpResponse(response_data)
        return response
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question as this only shows how to cache & retrieve raw data. The work that `cache_page()` does for you in terms of caching the entire response and setting headers is lost here.

Comment: to set cache_key Use: cache_key = learn_cache_key(request, response, timeout, self.key_prefix, cache=self.cache) and to set headers use: patch_response_headers(response, timeout). refer UpdateCacheMiddleware class